How to write JSDoc if name of property is string, like 'aria-label'
I want to write JSDoc for some React component:
/**
 * Some Component
 * @param {Object} props - props of the component
 * @param {boolean} [props.active=false] - active
 * @param {string} props.text - text
 * ...
 * @returns {React.ReactElement} Some Component
 */

How can I correctly add property named 'aria-label' in JSDoc?
I can't find the necessary solution in the Net.

Object property names with hyphens doesn't seem to be well-supported by JSDoc. Maybe try * @param {string} props.aria-label - an alternative label?

It does not work.

After some investigation it appears that JSDoc doesn't support params with hyphens in their name.

@param {string} props['aria-label'] - your description

or in case it is not a part of props object:
@param {string} ['aria-label'] - your description


It does not work.
